# lenovo screen suddenly messed up

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, display, thinkpad

I have a new lenovo thinkpad E420. Was working fine all day yesterday after i did a fresh install of windows 7 x64 on it and installed all the lenovo drivers from their official support website.

However i just turned it on and now the screen is unreadable, you cannot read the text clearly and the screen itself looks like it has flipped, not rotated but flipped horizontally. Even the bios boot screen is flipped! The resolution of the screen also looks very low and grainy.

Please help!! It has switchable gfx inside, intel HD and ATI card.

Comment: restarting the computer does not fix it...

Comment: What does the display look like if you start in safe mode?

Comment: same the screen still flipped and blurry...

Comment: just so weird even the bios screen is messed up so how can it be a windows problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a new laptop, you should contact Lenovo for a repair. This is a hardware problem and nothing to do with Windows

Edit: If it is still under warranty, do not open the laptop to reseat anything without first contacting the vendor and checking your warranty terms and conditions

Comment: My gf is blaming me saying i shouldnt have installed windows ultimate on it (it only had home version before) so your are sure this is not windows problem?

Comment: Positive, the BIOS display is totally independent of Windows

Comment: Lol ok, just enjoyed 30 minutes of being shouted at while trying to explain the same... time for a beer. The laptop's been handled carefully and never opened up so warranty should cover it.

Comment: back from service center, it is screen hardware problem... they plugged it into an external monitor and it worked fine. Repair time.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, now go get the gf to make it up to you

Comment: @tiaowuu8 At least you can tell your gf that it could have died at any time, and you just caught it early enough it was still in warranty.